# HTML 500 Tomcat Java

Tags: java, tomcat

I was trying to learn how to do Java Web Application with tomcat
I am off to good start but when i try to load my servlet class i am getting 500 error

### My newPlayer.java file:

```
    package servlet;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;


    /**
     * Created by kbuczynski on 24/01/17.
     */

    public class newPlayer extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {

        protected void doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
        }

        protected void doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.print("<h1>HI</h1>");
            out.flush();
        }
}
```

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>WeBJ</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>newPlayer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet.newPlayer</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>newPlayer</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/newPlayer</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

### Error:

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class servlet.newPlayer
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:495)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:767)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1347)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: servlet.newPlayer
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1275)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1109)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:495)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:767)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1347)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

### File Structure

[CLICK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzHRy.png)

I am always happy to take any advice so feel free to do so.

Comment: Are you sure that your servlet is part of your classpath?

Comment: How are you trying to install and run the servlet?  Are you placing the class and web.xml under the ROOT of tomcat?  Placing web.xml at webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml and classes under 
webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/

Comment: Check your deployment descriptor to see if the Classes are being deployed to the right location or not ... (WEB-INF/classes) to be precise.

Comment: `<servlet-class>com.yourPackageName.yourServletName</servlet-class>` try with this and please give me a feedback.

Comment: I tried com.* did not worked. not sure how u check where they being deployed as i never worked with tomcat

I am running tomcat on a vagrant vm machine. I mounted the directory in /srv/ and created soft link from web directory to webapps. I think thats ok as i can load my index.jsp file fine. 

@perbellinio not sure how you check that

Comment: Your artefact might a jar or war, so you can open it and check if your servlet is there.

Comment: I had a look to the file structure and it looks a bit weird. Usually the java class are under src/main/java and Intellij is able to recognise the java folder as a source folder. It might be that your project is not well configured.

Comment: @perbellinio can you show me good structure for a project as i would like to  do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

A good project structure might be the one followed by maven: [project-structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).
I have a small servlet project on my github that is using maven as a build tool: [simple-servlet](https://github.com/perbellinioa/java/tree/master/simple-servlet).

Comment: cheers that should help (hopefully) i give it at go soon and post how it went
cheers for help +1

Comment: so I did tried it and i am getting same error with example you have provided (i clone the project and runned it through tomcat) I am starting to think its a tom cat issue not project.
I am using tomcat9.

Comment: I have only tested it with tomcat7. Do you have maven installed? If yes you can run the project with command line: mvn clean install tomcat7:run

Comment: Installing netbeans and deploying project there helped.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

OK With help from @perbelinio i realised that Intellij is useless for it. I have installed netbeans and deployed my project. After few changes in a code it worked.
Thanks for help :)